# In excel, how can I identify which named ranges are not referenced in other sheets

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

I have an excel workbook with thousands of named references on one worksheet. Is there VBA code that can tell me which of these references are not utilized (within formulas) in any of the other worksheets (there are more than 25 of them).

Comment: What VBA code have you written to achieve your goal yourself? Stack Overflow doesn't exist for others to write code for you, it exists to help you solve problems you're having with code you've written.

Comment: I have code that can help me identify named ranges but I cant seem to find how to then serch for how they are referenced.  I am trying to find a way to shirnk the excel spreadhsheet I have from 25MB to a much smaller size.  I have to tweak the output of the query toonly return the data I need.  I am not looking necessarily for a full piece of code, but rather a starting point.

Comment: http://excelribbon.tips.net/T010998_Finding_Unused_Names.html

Answer (score 0):

One edit.  In the end I did use a lot of the getridofnames Thank you Tim.  I had to modify it a lot and it has to cycle through every worksheet.  It is cumbersome but I think it works.

Sub RidOfNames()
    Dim myName As Name
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim fdMsg As String
    Dim t As Boolean

```
'Search for Sheet1 - If it doesnt exist create it
Dim wsTest As Worksheet
Const strSheetName As String = "Sheet1"

Set wsTest = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set wsTest = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName)
On Error GoTo 0

If wsTest Is Nothing Then
    Worksheets.Add.Name = strSheetName
End If

'Clear all of Sheet1
Sheet1.Cells.Clear

i = 0
On Error Resume Next
fdMsg = ""
For Each myName In Names
    t = False
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            'Do not search Raw Data or Sheet 1 - or it has already been found
            If ws.Name = "Sheet1" Or ws.Name = "Raw Data" Or t = True Then GoTo myNext
            ws.Select
            ws.Range("A1").Select
            If Cells.Find(What:=myName.Name, _
               After:=ActiveCell, _
               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
               LookAt:=xlPart, _
               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
               SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
               MatchCase:=False, _
               SearchFormat:=False).Activate Is Nothing Then
                             ' it was not found
                                                        Else
                    t = True ' it was found!
            End If
```

myNext:
            End With

```
    Next ws
If t = False Then
    fdMsg = fdMsg & myName.Name & vbCr
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Value = myName.Name
    i = i + 1  'increment placement of found named ranges
    t = False  'set test variable back to false
End If
Next myName
If fdMsg = "" Then
    MsgBox "No unused names found in the workbook"
Else
    MsgBox "Names Not Used:" & vbCr & fdMsg
End If
```

End Sub